# jquery - changing object attribute after creating instance on document.ready()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bxslider

i'm using the bxSlider plugin (a slider similar to jcarousel) on custom Magento store.

While the slider is istantiated on documet.ready() (in the head html section) by this way:

```
jQuery('#slider2').bxSlider({
    pause: 4000,
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    displaySlideQty: 4,
    moveSlideQty: 1
});
```

I want to change auto attribute to false in the php code if the slider items count is less than 5. I've tried to change it with:

```
<?php
    // slider items count
    $prom_count = $this->getPromotionalProducts()->count();;
?>
<?php if($prom_count<5): ?>
    <script>
        $("#slider2").attr('auto','false');    
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but it doesn't work, so i'm not sure that attribute of objects instantiated on dom ready can be changed by this way. anybody could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr`-method from the jQuery-library works with attributes for HTML-elements:

```
<img src="..." alt="...">
```

In this case, `src` and `alt` are "attributes".

The bxSlider is configured by giving the `bxSlider`-function an array. You can't alter this array after it was passed to the function.

What you can do to toggle the auto-show is using bxSlider's `stopShow()`-function. To probably do this, you'll want to save the bxSlider-instance you created:

```
var slider = jQuery('#slider2').bxSlider({
   ...
});
```

So you can then call the function on this object:

```
slider.stopShow();
```

Doing this with PHP and JavaScript in a mixed way (like you suggested) is ugly and should be avoided.

Instead, you should use a JavaScript-only solution:

```
var slider = jQuery('#slider2').bxSlider({
   auto: true,
   ...
});
if (slider.getSlideCount() < 5){
  slider.stopShow();
}
```

Note that `getSlideCount()` returns the number of slides, which is not guarantied to be the number of Images in the gallery! The number of slides displayed at once can be set by the `displaySlideQty`-attribute. The default however is 1.

---

It seams that there is a Bug which causes the `startShow` and `stopShow`-functions not to work: https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/pull/43

As a dirty workaround, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        jQuery('#slider2').bxSlider({
            pause: 4000,
            autoControls: true,
            displaySlideQty: 4,";
    if($prom_count >= 5) echo "auto: true,";
    echo "moveSlideQty: 1
        });
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. well i tried your solution but still doesn work. this is the code in the general .js file called in the head document section: http://dpaste.com/648712/
it doesnt work and i can have the items count only in the body section...

Comment: I realized, this seams to be a problem and there is a fix which waits to be pulled in the project: https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/pull/43 So you'll need to wait or find another solution...

Comment: That does stop the slide but it does not change the auto parameter. Because as you said it can't be changed by any given function.

Comment: The intention is to only make an auto-slide when there are more then 5 pictures. This should do the job.

Comment: Updated my answer. This should work until there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no [API](http://bxslider.com/options) function for this. Maybe the config will be loaded again if you use reloadShow(). If that does not help you have to read the [source code](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/blob/master/source/jquery.bxSlider.js).

Comment: There is a function which does this. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

That will set the `auto` attribute on the element it self, not the auto option of the plugin. It doesn't look like the plugin has the ability to change options after you have instantiated it, although I only had a quick look.

Can you not set the right `auto` value when you run the plugin by putting the php code first?

Comment: no, since the template and the php code that generate the slider html section is not the same of the head part...i can have the slider items count only in the body html section